# CSS on Select Boxes for Windows Not Working like OSX

Tags: css, django

I have a piece of code that isn't working on Windows/Android but works fine on OSX and Linux. I know it has something to do with the CSS, but I can't figure out the issue. All the data in the select boxes don't display in the box. Both images below have the same values chosen.

**Windows**

[image: Windows]

**OSX**

[image: OSX]

Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
input::placeholder {
            color: dodgerblue;
        }

        .filter-form {
            font-size: .75em;
        }

        .filter-form select {
            color: dodgerblue;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 15px;
            display: block;
            height: 35px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
            font-family: "PT Sans", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .filter-form input {
            color: dodgerblue;
            border-radius: 0;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 15px;
            display: block;
            height: 35px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid dodgerblue;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: "PT Sans", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
        }
```

And the code from the page:

```
<div class="product-filter">

                    <h3>Filter By:</h3>

                    <div class="sort">

                        <div class="collection-sort filter-form">
                            <form method="get">
                                {{ filter.form.as_p }}
                                <button class="btn-a btn-a_size_small btn-a_color_theme" type="submit"
                                        style="margin:10px 0;">Filter Results
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: If you drag your cursor over the box, is the text there, but the same colour as the background? Is the content sitting on the next line? Off to one side? etc.

Comment: That was something I thought about early on. No such luck though. In the inspector I can see the values, but nothing shows on the rendering of the boxes in Windows